# How do I trace or debug the values of s_printf()?

Tags: c, visual-c++

I'm trying to trace the values of the s_printf() for it's corresponding variables & values. I'm assuming it's the same what's being displayed in this .log file

```
if ( *(_BYTE *)v1 )
{
  v26 = sub_140004750();
  
  v27 = COERCE_UNSIGNED_INT64(sub_140005FA0(v1));
  
  v28 = v6;
  
  sprintf_s(
    &DstBuf,
    0x1F4ui64,
    "CONTROL_LOAD: Slave=%d,curTime=%.1f; MaxTrq=%.3f (MaxTrqGain=%.3f+HydFailTrq=%.3f), loadCell=%.3f, speedTgt=%d "
    "dt_sonePos=%.1f; dt2=%.1f; dt_soneSetSpd=%.1f; dt3=%.1f; dt_soneMaxTrq=%.1f\n",
    *(unsigned int *)(v1 + 152),
    v26,
    v9,
    *(float *)(v1 + 376),
    *(float *)(v1 + 740),
    v27, //MaxTrq
    v28, //
    *(double *)&qword_1400239E0 - *(double *)&qword_1400239D8,
    *(double *)&qword_1400239E8 - *(double *)&qword_1400239E0,
    *(double *)&qword_1400239F0 - *(double *)&qword_1400239E8,
    *(double *)&qword_1400239F8 - *(double *)&qword_1400239F0,
    *(double *)&qword_140023A00 - *(double *)&qword_1400239F8);
  OutputDebugStringA(&DstBuf);
}
```

Below is one of the section of the .log file

```
00000017    0.00175577    [5084] CONTROL_LOAD: Slave=4, curTime=31482.1; MaxTrq=20.000 (MaxTrqGain=17.400+HydFailTrq=18.200), loadCell=-118.944, speedTgt=36400 dt_sonePos=0.0; dt2=26107.7; dt_soneSetSpd=0.7; dt3=-15334.1; dt_soneMaxTrq=0.5
```

Could I have any guidance, I thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean trace the values ? In general you see them in the .log file. If yo uwant to make sure sprintf_s does the thing you expect, you can put values in temp variables and inspect them in the debugger.

Comment: `0x1F4ui64` looks invalid for an integer constant.  Is this really true working code?

Comment: @wohlstad I'm just trying to trace the variable according to the output log file value, so that I could capture the variable for each value if true. 

for example, is the variable:

v9 = (MaxTrq=%.3f is the value represented 20.000 in the logfile)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica

It's a working .exe file yes; I'm just trying to understand how it passes the values within it's source code as the documentation for each variable is unfortunately unavailable when i reverse engineered it disassembler - decompile -> visual c++